# Real Analysis question about proving limits using boundedness and monotony

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I am trying to get a hang of solving problems that ask to "prove the limit". One of the questions on our previous homework was:
[image]

The solution starts with

[image].

How do we know that sn is bounded below and not above? I believe the next step is to plug in the formula for *Sn+1* into ***Sn**^2 - x >= 0* but I am not sure why. I think I will understand the rest of the solution if you can help me understand this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$s_n$ is bounded below because if you examine the formula
$$
s_{n+1} = \frac{s_n^2 + x}{2s_n}
$$
then the numerator is positive. So as long as you know that $s_n$ is nonzero and nonnegative at each finite $n$ (nonzero so the formula is well-defined), $s_{n+1}$ will in fact be nonnegative, hence bounded below by $0$.

As to why $s_n$ is nonzero: if at some $n$ we had $s_n = 0$, but $s_m \neq 0$ for all $m < n$ (i.e. we find the earliest $n$ where we get $0$), then
$$
0 = \frac{s_{n-1}^2 + x}{2s_{n-1}}
$$
and therefore $s_{n-1}^2 + x = 0$. But $x>0$ and $s_{n-1}^2 \geq 0$, so this is impossible.

As to why $s_n$ is nonnegative: a similar argument, and proceeds by induction. You've got the base case for free.

Finally, showing why it's not bounded above: that's the rest of the proof!

Comment: Oh good point, thanks! and I just realized the numerator increases faster than the denominator so it must be bounded below. But then how do we know that our claim $sn >= \sqrt{x}$ should hold specifically for $n \ge 2$? Why not $n \ge 0$ or $n \ge 1$? Like for future problems, how can I determine that value?

Comment: Well, for $n=0$ and $n=1$ you just check directly. There are only 2 cases so this is fine. In any case it's not so important what the specific value of $N$ with $n\geq N$ being the requirement is; what's important is that you can show such a finite $N$ exists. Since you're taking limits anyway, you only care what happens at large $N$; terms near the beginning of the sequence don't matter so much.

Answer (score 2):

First by induction, it is easy to prove that $s_n>0$ for all n. Then

$$s_{n+1}=\dfrac{s^2_n+x} {2s_n}\geqslant \dfrac{2s_n\sqrt{x}}{2s_n}=\sqrt{x}$$

So $s_n$ is bound below. Now use induction to prove for all $n, s_{n}\leqslant s_{n-1}.$
For $n=2$
\begin{align}
s_2-s_1&=\dfrac{s^2_1+x}{2s_1}-s_1
\\
&=\dfrac{x-s^2_{1}}{2s_{1}}
\\
&\leqslant 0
\end{align}

Assume it be true for $k<n$, then

\begin{align}
s_{n+1}-s_n&=\dfrac{s^2_n+x} {2s_n}-\dfrac{s^2_{n-1}+x} {2s_{n-1}}
\\
&=\dfrac{s^2_ns_{n-1}-s_ns^2_{n-1}+x(s_{n-1}-s_{n})}{2s_ns_{n-1}}
\\
&=\dfrac{(s_{n-1}-s_{n})(x-s_{n-1}s_{n})}{2s_ns_{n-1}}
\\
&\leqslant 0 
\end{align}

The last step is true for $s_{n-1}-s_{n}\geqslant 0$ and $x-s_{n-1}s_{n}\leqslant 0$

Since $s_n$ is monotonic decreasing and bounded below, it has limt. By taking the limit on both side, we have

$$s=\dfrac{s^2+x} {2s} \quad\text{where}\quad s=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}s_n$$

Thus $s=\sqrt{x}$